# Await for proper connection to rabbit in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I try to write my simple eventemitter wrapper for amqplib/callback_api. I have trouble with handling sitaution when rabbit is not available or disconnected. 
I have method `getConnect` which returns Promise, which resolves when connection established. But if connection is refused Promise obviously rejects. How to force this method do reconnection while connection will not wstablished

```
/**
     * Async method getConnect for connection
     * @returns {Promise<*>}
     */
    getConnect = async () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            amqp.connect(this.config.url, async function(err, conn) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    }
                    resolve(conn);
            })
        })
    };
```

Whole code is here https://github.com/kimonniez/rabbitEE

Maybe, I'm already very sleepy, but I'm completely confused :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Wrap your [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) inside an [`Observable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs)

`Promise` is not built to handle *"retry"* logic. If you want to do that, you should look into **Observables** using the [`rxjs` library](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs). This will allow you to retry using an arbitrary time interval while catching errors.

```js
const { from, interval, of } = rxjs;
const { catchError, mergeMap, tap, skipWhile, take } = rxjs.operators;

const THRESHOLD = 3;
const RETRY_INTERVAL = 1000;

// Equivalent to 'amqp.connect'
const functionThatThrows = number =>
  number < THRESHOLD
    ? Promise.reject(new Error("ERROR"))
    : Promise.resolve("OK");

// Equivalent to `getConnect`
const getConnect = () =>
  interval(RETRY_INTERVAL)
    .pipe(
      mergeMap(x => from(functionThatThrows(x)).pipe(catchError(e => of(e)))),
      skipWhile(x => {
        const isError = x instanceof Error;
        if (isError) console.log('Found error. Retrying...');
        return isError;
      }),
      take(1)
    ).toPromise();

// Resolve only if the inner Promise is resolved
getConnect().then(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.4.0/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

## Explanation

1. Create a source with an `interval` of `1000`. Meaning that it will retry each second
2. Call your `amqp.connect` which is equivalent to `functionThatThrows` in my example
3. Catch the error using the `catchError` operator and return it
4. Skip while the returned object is an error. This will allow your to **resolve only if your `Promise` has been resolved and not rejected**
5. Take the first resolved result using `take(1)`
6. Convert your *observable* into a promise using the `toPromise` utility function
7. Call your function and attach `then` like you do with a standard `Promise`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I need to modificate my code for this new logic but anyway now it seems greate!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to keep tryng connecting until a connection is made, you can wrap the `getConnect` method into a new `keepConnect` method:

```
keepConnect = async () => {
   while (true) {
      try {
         let conn = await getConnect()
         return conn
      } catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

But I think it would be better to implement something like a "try to connect for n times", by changing the `while` condition. In general, a "while true" solution is not clean and could perform bad, with the risk to slow down the event loop  (imagine if the connect method will always return an error in few milliseconds).

You could also implement a system of progressive delays between connection attempts, using the `keepConnect` wrapper as idea.

If you instead want to reconnect when the connection is lost, then this is related to Rabbit (that I don't know) and his events.

Comment: Thx for u answer